# Windows Phone 8 Reserved URI / File Associations

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have read up on Uri and File type association for Windows Phone 8 Apps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx

and its is clearly documented that there are some file types that will always be handled by a particular windows phone application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207065(v=vs.105).aspx

But when you navigate to the photo gallery and select an image there is an option to "share" the image to apps that have seemingly been associated with that file type.

If you were to select a document in the office application you would see a smiliar share option in the context menu / app bar as well

How can my app also accept .jpgs / .pptx / .mp4 -s or other file types that are documented as being reserved, the same way the twitter or gmail app may receive an image being shared from the gallery?

Comment: The answer is pretty simple, its not done by file/uri association, its done by extending the Share Picker in WindowsPhone8.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967563(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Is there also a way to integrate the app into the URL share picker of IE, or photos only?

Comment: I havent yet found a way to do it for anything except photos, and that seemingly includes videos on the camera roll. Although I Imagine if you Could find the ExtensionName and ConsumerID of IE or or another app, that you could use this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Windows Phone 8.1, the best approach is to register as a target for the [share contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871369.aspx). This enables you to show up whenever the user wishes to share a file of a particular type from any app on the phone.

Prior to WP8.1, [extending the photos share picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is your only option.